# Using MySQL with Old Password and Doctrine running with Php 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.4

I have been trying to use Doctrine with Silex framework. I am using PHP 5.4. When I try to use database, I am getting the error:

`An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file`

Unfortunately, I am on a shared hosting and I do not have access to the `mysql` database to apply the `SET PASSWORD` command and update my password. The hosting provider is also not willing to upgrade it.

I did check all the threads for the fix for this issue - but all of them ask me to run the `SET SESSION` and `SET PASSWORD` queries on the `mysql` database.

Is there any other way by which I can use Doctrine with the older authentication for MySQL?

Comment: Maybe you have to find a proper hosting company which doesn't forces their customers to use old insecure authentication.

Comment: Lol! That is what I did :). Couldn't find any way to do this :(.